# Why in Apple Mail on Mac OS are my links showing up transparent?

Tags: css, email, styles, html-email

I don't do a whole lot of css and design much anymore... it works on every other platform i can think of except Apple Mail.

---

**Here's what it looks like on the desktop:**

[image]

---

As you can see the button for "SET A NEW PASSWORD" isn't showing up.

**iphone 7 using the same icloud but on mobile it shows like this:**

---

[image]

here it has the button and the link and in gmail it shows the button and the link too... as far as I know it's just an issue in Apple Mail on desktop.

```
<style>
    ul.ads-list li {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
<style>
   .main-content a, .main-content a:link, .main-content a:visited{
           color: #14b0de !important   
         }
</style>
```

Anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: When you say iCloud are you actually referring to Apple Mail (the app) on MacOS (desktop) and iOS (phone)? Or are you talking about how the email renders in the iCloud web viewer similar to Gmail in a browser?

Comment: Add a semicolon to the end of `color: #14b0de !important;` If you want actual help, post your html code so we can see what the issue might be and offer a fix.

Comment: @BryceHowitson Yes Apple Mail on MacOS it doesn't render the blue box or the link that says "Set a New Password".

Comment: @Supplement In that case, I edited your post to be clearer about that. For future reference, The Mail app does the rendering iCloud is only the server system for .mac email addresses.